# Set input textfield with form validation jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code;

```
<form data-test="loginForm-container" novalidate="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="css-o5d3v1 e1ovefus2">
    <div data-test="guestForm-email-wrapper" class="e1ovefus1 css-yjv4po e1eu3ser1">
        <div class="css-gg4vpm e1eu3ser4">
            <label for="guestForm-email" id="guestForm-email-label" data-test="input-label" class="css-1k1vx4d e1eu3ser5">Email Address*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="css-1tpy6sb e1eu3ser7">
            <input data-test="guestForm-email" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" id="guestForm-email" type="email" name="email" aria-labelledby="guestForm-email-label" class="css-15uq4zo e1eu3ser9" value="" aria-describedby="guestForm-email-error">
        </div><span data-test="input-error" id="guestForm-email-error" role="alert" class="css-mf5akt e1eu3ser0">Please enter email address</span></div>
</div>
<button type="submit" data-test="guestForm-submitButton" class="e1ovefus0 css-1wqqz58 e1y6awi20"><span>Continue as Guest</span></button>
```

I tried doing;

```
$("#guestForm-email").value = "test@gmail.com"
```

but when submit it deletes the text in textfield.

I just need to learn how to validate it in JQUERY.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Strictly speaking it doesn't delete the text; what happens is the form is sent, and the page reloads. (not stating the `action` attribute defaults to the current document) You need to use `$('form').on('submit', function () { ... });`, validate the fields inside the callback and return false if the validation fails to prevent submission (i.e. reload): https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/549g7nhr/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly this has to do with validation, but this is not how you set a value to a form element in jQuery:

```
$("#guestForm-email").value = "test@gmail.com"
```

[This is](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#guestForm-email").val("test@gmail.com")
```

Comment: it still deletes on submit. I need to validate the form with this somehow

Comment: @Bob: "validate" how exactly?  Is it "deleting" when you submit the form, or is it *submitting* and just reloading the page?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do, and the only line of code you have appears to just be setting a value.  (Trying to, anyway)  What specifically are you trying to do and where are you trying to do it?

Comment: It is deleting the text and not reloading the page.

Comment: @Bob: Can you provide a more complete example?  Neither your one line of erroneous JavaScript code, nor the one line in this answer, would delete a value nor prevent the form from submitting.  There has to be more to whatever you're doing.

Comment: do you think it has to do with the aria-required tag?

Comment: @Bob: I think that examining and debugging a complete example which fully and minimally demonstrates the problem would be more productive than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant write this as

```
$("#guestForm-email").value = "test@gmail.com"
```

this is the correct syntax

```
$("#guestForm-email").val("test@gmail.com")
```

and try to do this in function that return true if the data is valid an call it in

```
<form onSubmit="return validate()">
```

Comment: my way worked but your way it still deletes text on submit

Comment: if the page get refreshed and the inputs get empty then the the data are valide and you re good

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to do is to validate the e-mail sent on the input text field using jQuery. You can use a reg expression for this within your button's click event handler like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button[type=submit]").click(function() {
        if(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test($("#guestForm-email").value)) {
            return $("#guestForm-email").value;
        } else {
            alert("Invalid E-mail");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what “ /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/” is?

Comment: That is a reg expression. It simply checks to see that what the user has enter is a valid e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to append text inside input:

```
$("#guestForm-email").val($("#guestForm-email").val()+"test@gmail.com")
```